# Lambdas and Exception handling

Tags: c#, exception, lambda

I have something like the following:

```
public class FooWrapper
{
    public Action Foo { get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            Foo.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
                //exception is null
            //do something interesting with the exception 
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my unit test with something like the following:

```
new FooWrapper() { Foo = () => { throw new Exception("test"); } };
```

The exception is thrown as expected but and the catch steps through but "exception" is null. How do I get to the exception thrown by an .Invoke() to properly handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in the code inside your catch block.  The exception value in a catch block as defined by your sample cannot ever be null.  There must be a non-null exception value for that code to execute.

Can you post the contents of your catch block?

Answer (score 2):

It only ever appears null if you have a breakpoint **outside** the `exception` line; inside, it should be non-null. I've just tested it, and got an `Exception` with `Message="test"`, as expected.